# is there a way to use fabric run() and sudo() at a time?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, sudo, fabric

I'm trying to automate a test in python 2.7 (in eclipse on linux ubuntu 12.04).
The test checks configurations on another pc, so I'm using fabric for the ssh connection.

I need to execute a script:

```
run("cd somepath && ./execute_script.sh")
```

The problem is that my script needs a sudo to run, but changing the command to this:

```
sudo("cd somepath && ./execute_script.sh")
```

does not work since "cd" doesn't work in combination with sudo.
I also cannot split the command in two parts, because that would create 2 shells, and the second one would forget the path I've been going to in the first one.

If I do it like this:

```
run("cd somepath && sudo ./execute_script.sh")
```

the test wouldn't work completely automatic since you would have to enter the password at a time.

Is there a way to some sort of combine run() and sudo()?

Comment: How about `sudo("sh -c 'cd somepath && ./execute_script.sh'")`

Comment: Thank you very much, I just searched up "sh" after seeing your comment, that helps a ton in many of my tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
from fabric.api import cd,sudo
with cd('somepath'):
    sudo('./execute_script.sh')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it worked for me, I didn't even knew something like that is possible, I think I might need to do some extra research before coding